# how can i get the prime numbers (Goldbach's Conjecture in c# windows form application)

Tags: c#, primes

i'm creating a windows form application of goldbach's conjecture. my problem is, i keep getting odd numbers instead of prime. how can i get the prime numbers only? this is what i've done so far

i've found some codes which are in console application which i've tried to put in windows form application, but i don't know how. any help will be appreciated thanks!

the program accepts an input of even number then displays all possible combination

e.g.
Input: 14

Output: 3+11; 7+7

but what i'm getting is

Input: 14

Output: 3+11; 5+9; 7+7; 9+5;

** Sorry for deleting

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Case_Study
{
    public partial class frmGBC : Form
    {
        public frmGBC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        String holder, holder2;
        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int number = int.Parse(txtInput.Text);
            if (number % 2 == 0)
            {
                lvContainer.Items.Add("Input: " + number + ":\n");
                lvContainer.Items.Add("Solutions:");
            }
            if (number < 1001)
            {
                if (number < 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Must be greater than 2!");
                    holder = "";
                }
                    if (number % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        if (number % 2 == 0 && number <= 1000 && number >= 10)
                        {
                            for (int i = 3; i < number - 3; i += 2)
                            {
                                holder =+ i + " + " + (number - i) + "; ";
                            }
                        }
                        if (number % 2 == 0 && number <= 8 && number >= 4)
                        {
                            for (int i = 3; i < number; i += 2)
                            {
                                holder =i + " + " + (number - i) + ";";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Must be even number!");
                    }
                }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Maximum input is 1000!");
            }
        }
        private void frmGBC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lvContainer.Columns.Add("Goldbach's Conjecture", 118);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: where is your algorithm to check for prime numbers? Forgive me if you have one and I didn't see it.......

Comment: the algorithm for checking prime numbers is on the for loop

Comment: @rjsu Are you asking for the proper algorithm to find primes or for a tutorial in winforms? Is this homework?

Comment: i'm asking about how to get the proper algorithm for getting the prime numbers which will be used in goldbach's conjecture. to be specific, this is a case study

Comment: Please explain how `for (int i = 3; i < number - 3; i += 2)` is an algorithm for checking prime numbers.

Comment: I've rolled back. you shouldn't remove the code from the question about the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done a good work but you forgot to check for prime numbers in your for loop before adding it into holder. I have one function that I just code that may be handy for you.(Not the best way to check prime)

```
        bool isprime(int num)
    {
        if(num<2)
        {

            return false;

        }
        else if(num==2)
        {
            return true;

        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=2; i<=num/2;i++)
            {
                if(num % i==0)
                {
                    return false;

                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

** I deleted his code part because he is saying someone is stealing his code. Sorry!!

Comment: oh my god thank you so much! this solves my problem! i'm truly grateful for your help :))

Comment: @rjsu No problem , Happy Programming!!